# How to adjust text as justified in div tag

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="text-align:justify; text-justify:newspaper;width:300px;height:200px;border:1px solid">
<p>
We are a mix of young, energetic individuals mentored by experienced seniors who as a team are passionate about continually moving out of our comfort <br> zones.
some text

</div>
```

I have lots of text to add on webpage. I am unable to adjust text as justified.
from left side it is okay but on right hand side it not okay.. please tell me the changes.
I want to add text as like in newspaper format..

Comment: The text looks justified to me in the example you posted.

Comment: FYI `text-justify:newspaper;` is IE only, so best to avoid more than likely

Comment: it will only looks like on jsfiddle... not on my any browser, why it so?

Comment: Just noted, you aren't closing the `p` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/945cn/1/

You had a random, unneeded `<p>` tag without a closing `</p>` tag so I removed it. Also, I suggest not using inline css and putting the css in a style sheet as I show in my JSFiddle. Let me know if this works for you.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="justified">
    We are a mix of young, energetic individuals mentored by experienced seniors who as a team are passionate about continually moving out of our comfort
    <br>zones. some text
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.justified {
    text-align:justify;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid
}
```

Comment: very funny...nothing difference in your code and my code

Comment: I removed the p tag, and I set your style as a class instead of inline. It displays properly on all browsers for me. Perhaps you have conflicting css?